# Select employees who took 5 or more days of vacation in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to select `staffId` (employees), who took 5 or more days of vactions in a row

```
select * from dbo.EmployeeRecords where reasonId = 3 and isPaid = 1
```

`reasonId = 3` means vacation

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: How will holidays factor into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `lead()` -- assuming you have no more than one row per day and there are no gaps in the `workday` column.  So, to get the first day of such vacations:

```
select er.*
from (select er.*,
             lead(workday, 4) over (partition by staffid order by workday) as workday_4
      from dbo.EmployeeRecords er
      where reasonId = 3 and isPaid = 1
     ) er
where workday_4 = dateadd(day, 4, workday);
```

The "4" is one less than "5", because the current date already counts as one day.

If you have weekends in the middle and need to take those into account, then 5 days is conveniently one week.  You can use:

```
where workday_4 <= dateadd(day, 6, workday);
```

That just happens to work easily because 5 days equals a week.  Otherwise you need to take the day of week into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query using subquery with count operator

```
select * from dbo.EmployeeRecords 
where staffid in 
(
    select staffid 
        from 
        (
        select staffid, count(staffid) cnt rownum
        from dbo.EmployeeRecords 
        where reasonId = 3 and isPaid = 1
        group by staffid
        )t
        where t.cnt>=5
)
```

Comment: That's wouldn't guarantee there were five in a row.